# Find eigen value without expand and factor

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I would like to compute the eigen value of the matrix:

$$\begin{pmatrix}2& 0 & 4 \\ 3 & -4& 12 \\ 1& -2&5\end{pmatrix}$$

By expand the determinant of $\det(M-XId) = (2-X)\times(\dots) + 4 \times (\dots)$ and then factorize it I finaly get the characteristic polynomial: $X(2-X)(X-1)$.

I can't figure out how to find this factorized form with "nice computation", using "kind of Gauss algorithm".

Comment: There is no nice way to calculate the characteristic polynomial; it is a $O(n!)$ procedure no matter what you do. This is one of several reasons why this method is almost never used in the real world.

Comment: I know that, but this is an exercise for fresh students, I was hopping some nicer method.

Comment: It is "nice" for "fresh" students in the sense that it is only a $3\times 3$ matrix.  What if they'd asked you to compute eigenvalues of a much larger matrix?